# How to match between the nth occurrence and nth +1 occurrence using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text:

```
aBcD-19/WES/VA-MKL-2217223/2020
```

I would like to extract what is between the 2nd occurrence of / and the 3rd occurrence of /. Based on the text, the following will be extracted

```
VA-MKL-2217223
```

So far I came out with this pattern '\S+?/' which gives me 3 matches. That it, whats behind each /. I only want to depend on the slashes.

Comment: Always ask yourself "why am I using a regex for this?" because there's a lot of string operations built into lots of programming languages already.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I actually wanted the regex method for this one.

Comment: Then please explain _why_ because regular string splitting already does this job without any need for regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> s='aBcD-19/WES/VA-MKL-2217223/2020'
```

You can do:

```
>>> s.split('/')[2]
'VA-MKL-2217223'
```

Or with a regex:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?:[^/]+/){2}([^/]+)',s).group(1)
'VA-MKL-2217223'
```